# Escaping problem with find command

Tags: bash, scripting, find, quoting

I need to find everything in a directory, excluding certain subdirectories and files. My script needs to call this as a function:

```
function findStuff() {
  # define exclusions
  ignore_dirs=("$1" "*foo*")                        # exclude base dir
  ignore_files=("one.txt" "two.txt" "*three*.txt")
  # build patterns for find command
  dir_pattern=""
  file_pattern=""
  for i in "${ignore_dirs[@]}"; do dir_pattern=$dir_pattern" ! -path \"$i\""; done
  for i in "${ignore_files[@]}"; do file_pattern=$file_pattern" ! -name \"$i\""; done
  # find
  find "$1 $dir_pattern $file_pattern"
  # now do other stuff with the results...
}

findStuff /some/base/dir
```

But this gives me a `No such file or directory` error.

So I wanted to see what the command actually was and tried `echo find "$1 $dir_pattern $file_pattern"` and pasted that on the command line and it worked. Then I pasted that into the script and run it, and it also worked!

So i think it's failing because of some escaping problem. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`find` will use the first arguments (up to the first argument that starts with `-` or that is `!` or `(`) that it gets as the top-level paths to search.  You are giving `find` a single argument when you call it in your function, the string `$1 $dir_pattern $file_pattern` (with the variables expanded).  This path is not found.

You also include literal double quotes in the arguments that you intend  do give to `find`.  Double quoting is done to prevent the shell from expanding glob patterns and from splitting on whitespaces (or whatever the `IFS` variable contains), but if you use e.g. `! -name \"thing\"` then the double quotes would be part of the pattern that `find` uses to compare against the filenames.

Use arrays, and quote the separate arguments to `find` properly:

```
myfind () {
  local ignore_paths=( "$1" "*foo*" )
  local ignore_names=( "one.txt" "two.txt" "*three*.txt" )

  local path_args=()
  for string in "${ignore_paths[@]}"; do
      path_args+=( ! -path "$string" )
  done

  local name_args=()
  for string in "${ignore_names[@]}"; do
      name_args+=( ! -name "$string" )
  done

  find "$1" "${path_args[@]}" "${name_args[@]}"
}
```

Each time we append to `path_args` and `name_args` above, we add three elements to the list, `!`, `-path` or `-name`, and `"$string"`.  When expanding `"${path_args[@]}"` and `"${name_args[@]}"` (note the double quotes), the elements will be individually quoted.

---

Equivalent implementation suitable for `/bin/sh`:

```
myfind () (
    topdir=$1

    set --

    # paths to ignore
    for string in "$topdir" "*foo*"; do
        set -- "$@" ! -path "$string"
    done

    # names to ignore
    for string in "one.txt" "two.txt" "*three*.txt"; do
        set -- "$@" ! -name "$string"
    done

    find "$topdir" "$@"
)
```

In the `sh` shell we only have a single array available to us, which is the list of positional parameters, `$@`, so we collect our `find` options in that.  The `bash`-specific solution could also be written to use a single array, obviously, and the `sh` variation would run in `bash` too.

---

And lastly, the output of your `echo` test is not an accurate representation of the command that would have been executed by your function.

Consider this:

```
cat "my file name"
```

which runs `cat` on something called `my file name`, and

```
echo cat "my file name"
```

which outputs the string `cat my file name`. This is due to the fact that the shell removes quotes around strings before executing the command.  Running *that* command, `cat` would look for *three* files, not one.

Your command worked well when you copy-pasted it into the shell, because you included the literal double quotes in the string that was outputted by `echo` (by escaping them), but that was not the actual command executed by your function.

Comment: What I don't get is the man pages said I should quote the args, so for example `-name "somefile.txt"` or `-name 'somefile.txt'` that is why I quoted above. In your code this is not done, but it works perfectly anyway... why?

Comment: @lonix The arguments to `-name` and `-path` should be quoted to prevent word splitting and filename globbing, yes.  I do quote these (`"$string"` in my code).  The double quotes will be stripped off by the shell before the argument is handed over to `find` so `find` will see the "raw contents" of `$string` but no quotes.  This is how it should be.